# How to match hostname in .htaccess using regular expression?

Tags: wordpress, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, bots

I am trying to block a bot using .htaccess in my WordPress site.

The host name is: `ec2-D1-D2-D3-D4.us-east-2.compute.amazonaws.com`

Where D1, D2, D3, D4 are sequnce of 1-3 digits, ie. [0-9]+ will match.

In some cases only D1,D2 & D3 exists.

I am trying:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} ^ec2-[0-9]+-[0-9]+-[0-9]+\.us\-east\-2\.compute\.amazonaws\.com$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} ^ec2\-[0-9]+\-[0-9]+\-[0-9]+\-[0-9]+\.us\-east\-2\.compute\.amazonaws\.com$ 

RewriteRule ^.*$ - [F,L]
```

It does not seem to work. What am I missing?

Comment: Did you put the code above your wordpress `RewriteRules` ?

Comment: @AmitVerma Yes. First lines in .htaccess

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Could you please try following, fair warning haven't tested it, also fixed your regex here and `HTTP_REFERER` doesn't directly starts from hotname so removed `^` part before your hostname too here(all values are samples/test values provided in question only).

```
RewriteEngine ON
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} ec2-([0-9]+-){1,}[0-9]+\.us-east-2\.compute\.amazonaws\.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^ - [F,L]
```

Comment: Not working. Thanks for compacting the regular expression.

Comment: @Mulli, whatever examples I saw from documentations this should work your referrer should either starts from http or https, how about clearing cache and trying once.

Comment: I prefer: ```RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} ec2(-[0-9]+){3,4}\.us-east-2\.compute\.amazonaws\.com [NC]
```

Comment: @Mulli, sure, thanks for sharing, if that works for you then why not :) though I had written it as per shown samples but you know your samples better than us :)

Comment: Or one could add `^http[s]?://(?:www\.)` too before `ec2` condition too(in case its applicable to wordpress's referrer value).